# Crackling during Skype calls, what can I do?

Tags: sound, skype, audacity

I've been trying to find tutorials or bug fixes to help with this, but no matter what I do I keep getting complaints that my input is "staticky" (their word, not mine lol)

Specs:

```
Computer

Summary
Computer
Processor   6x AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor
Memory  4030MB (1803MB used)
Operating System    Ubuntu 15.04
User Name   kara (Kara)
Date/Time   Fri 01 May 2015 11:11:26 PM EDT
Display
Resolution  2560x1024 pixels
OpenGL Renderer Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAPE VERDE
X11 Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Multimedia
Audio Adapter   HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
Audio Adapter   HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
Input Devices
Power Button    
Power Button    
Logitech USB Receiver   
Logitech USB Receiver   
KMEPC USB Full Speed Gaming Mouse   
HDA ATI SB Front Mic    
HDA ATI SB Rear Mic 
HDA ATI SB Line 
HDA ATI SB Line Out 
HDA ATI SB Front Headphone  
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    3=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    7=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    8=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    9=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    10=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    11=
Printers
No printers found   
SCSI Disks
ATA WDC WD1600AAJS-7    
ATA ST31000528AS    
Operating System
Version
Kernel  Linux 3.19.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Compiled    #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015
C Library   Unknown
Default C Compiler  GNU C Compiler version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)
Distribution    Ubuntu 15.04
Current Session
Computer Name   karapc
User Name   kara (Kara)
Home Directory  /home/kara
Desktop Environment Unity (ubuntu)
Misc
Uptime  8 hours, 18 minutes
Load Average    0.79, 0.95, 0.93
Kernel Modules
Loaded Modules
cfg80211    wireless configuration support
binfmt_misc 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi  HDMI HD-audio codec
snd_hda_codec_realtek   Realtek HD-audio codec
snd_hda_codec_generic   Generic HD-audio codec parser
snd_hda_intel   Intel HDA driver
snd_hda_controller  Common HDA driver funcitons
snd_hda_codec   HDA codec core
snd_hwdep   Hardware dependent layer
snd_pcm Midlevel PCM code for ALSA.
snd_seq_midi    Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer MIDI synth.
snd_seq_midi_event  MIDI byte <-> sequencer event coder
snd_rawmidi Midlevel RawMidi code for ALSA.
snd_seq Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer.
snd_seq_device  ALSA sequencer device management
amdkfd  Standalone HSA driver for AMD's GPUs
amd_iommu_v2    
snd_timer   ALSA timer interface
radeon  ATI Radeon
ttm TTM memory manager subsystem (for DRM device)
drm_kms_helper  DRM KMS helper
drm DRM shared core routines
snd Advanced Linux Sound Architecture driver for soundcards.
i2c_algo_bit    I2C-Bus bit-banging algorithm
soundcore   Core sound module
kvm_amd 
kvm 
shpchp  Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver
wmi ACPI-WMI Mapping Driver
crct10dif_pclmul    T10 DIF CRC calculation accelerated with PCLMULQDQ.
crc32_pclmul    
ghash_clmulni_intel GHASH Message Digest Algorithm, acclerated by PCLMULQDQ-NI
aesni_intel Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, Intel AES-NI instructions optimized
aes_x86_64  Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, asm optimized
lrw LRW block cipher mode
gf128mul    Functions for multiplying elements of GF(2^128)
serio_raw   Raw serio driver
glue_helper 
ablk_helper 
cryptd  Software async crypto daemon
i2c_piix4   PIIX4 SMBus driver
fam15h_power    AMD Family 15h CPU processor power monitor
k10temp AMD Family 10h+ CPU core temperature monitor
edac_core   Core library routines for EDAC reporting
edac_mce_amd    AMD MCE decoder
mac_hid 
parport_pc  PC-style parallel port driver
ppdev   
lp  
parport 
autofs4 
hid_generic HID generic driver
usbhid  USB HID core driver
hid 
pata_acpi   SCSI low-level driver for ATA in ACPI mode
psmouse PS/2 mouse driver
r8169   RealTek RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver
ahci    AHCI SATA low-level driver
pata_atiixp low-level driver for ATI IXP200/300/400
libahci Common AHCI SATA low-level routines
mii MII hardware support library
Boots
Boots
Languages
Available Languages
en_AG   English language locale for Antigua and Barbuda
en_AG.utf8  English language locale for Antigua and Barbuda
en_AU.utf8  English locale for Australia
en_BW.utf8  English locale for Botswana
en_CA.utf8  English locale for Canada
en_DK.utf8  English locale for Denmark
en_GB.utf8  English locale for Britain
en_HK.utf8  English locale for Hong Kong
en_IE.utf8  English locale for Ireland
en_IN   English language locale for India
en_IN.utf8  English language locale for India
en_NG   English locale for Nigeria
en_NG.utf8  English locale for Nigeria
en_NZ.utf8  English locale for New Zealand
en_PH.utf8  English language locale for Philippines
en_SG.utf8  English language locale for Singapore
en_US.utf8  English locale for the USA
en_ZA.utf8  English locale for South Africa
en_ZM   English locale for Zambia
en_ZM.utf8  English locale for Zambia
en_ZW.utf8  English locale for Zimbabwe
Filesystems
Mounted File Systems
udev    /dev    0.00 % (1.9 GiB of 1.9 GiB)
tmpfs   /run    4.06 % (377.6 MiB of 393.6 MiB)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/32298ba9-14c7-458a-8de6-6835beff24be  /   13.30 % (123.7 GiB of 142.6 GiB)
tmpfs   /dev/shm    0.63 % (1.9 GiB of 1.9 GiB)
tmpfs   /run/lock   0.08 % (5.0 MiB of 5.0 MiB)
tmpfs   /sys/fs/cgroup  0.00 % (1.9 GiB of 1.9 GiB)
cgmfs   /run/cgmanager/fs   0.00 % (100.0 KiB of 100.0 KiB)
tmpfs   /run/user/1000  0.01 % (393.5 MiB of 393.6 MiB)
Display
Display
Resolution  2560x1024 pixels
Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Version 1.17.1
Monitors
Monitor 0   1280x1024 pixels
Monitor 1   1280x720 pixels
Extensions
BIG-REQUESTS    
Composite   
DAMAGE  
DOUBLE-BUFFER   
DPMS    
DRI2    
GLX 
Generic Event Extension 
MIT-SCREEN-SAVER    
MIT-SHM 
Present 
RANDR   
RECORD  
RENDER  
SECURITY    
SGI-GLX 
SHAPE   
SYNC    
X-Resource  
XC-MISC 
XFIXES  
XFree86-DGA 
XFree86-VidModeExtension    
XINERAMA    
XInputExtension 
XKEYBOARD   
XTEST   
XVideo  
XVideo-MotionCompensation   
OpenGL
Vendor  X.Org
Renderer    Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAPE VERDE
Version 3.0 Mesa 10.5.2
Direct Rendering    Yes
Environment Variables
Environment Variables
GNOME_KEYRING_PID   
USER    kara
XDG_SEAT    seat0
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS   -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE   ubuntu
SESSION ubuntu
SHLVL   0
HOME    /home/kara
QT4_IM_MODULE   xim
DESKTOP_SESSION ubuntu
GTK_MODULES overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module
INSTANCE    
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS    unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-IIPJecU8AN
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL   
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME    appmenu-qt5
MANDATORY_PATH  /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
IM_CONFIG_PHASE 1
SESSIONTYPE gnome-session
LOGNAME kara
GTK_IM_MODULE   ibus
DEFAULTS_PATH   /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
XDG_SESSION_ID  c8
USERNAME    kara
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID    this-is-deprecated
WINDOWPATH  7:7:7:7
PATH    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR /run/user/1000
DISPLAY :0
LANG    en_US.UTF-8
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP Unity
XMODIFIERS  @im=ibus
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP ubuntu
XAUTHORITY  /var/run/gdm/auth-for-kara-eH6Qo5/database
SSH_AUTH_SOCK   /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
SHELL   /bin/bash
GDMSESSION  ubuntu
GPG_AGENT_INFO  /run/user/1000/keyring/gpg:0:1
UPSTART_SESSION unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/18037
XDG_VTNR    7
QT_IM_MODULE    ibus
PWD /home/kara
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE   xim
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
XDG_DATA_DIRS   /usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
JOB dbus
XDG_MENU_PREFIX gnome-
SESSION_MANAGER local/karapc:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/18276,unix/karapc:/tmp/.ICE-unix/18276
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE   /usr/share/applications/hardinfo.desktop
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID   22759
COMPIZ_BIN_PATH /usr/bin/
Users
Users
root    root
daemon  daemon
bin bin
sys sys
sync    sync
games   games
man man
lp  lp
mail    mail
news    news
uucp    uucp
proxy   proxy
www-data    www-data
backup  backup
list    Mailing List Manager
irc ircd
gnats   Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin)
nobody  nobody
systemd-timesync    systemd Time Synchronization
systemd-network systemd Network Management
systemd-resolve systemd Resolver
systemd-bus-proxy   systemd Bus Proxy
syslog  
messagebus  
uuidd   
avahi   Avahi mDNS daemon
dnsmasq dnsmasq
whoopsie    
avahi-autoipd   Avahi autoip daemon
speech-dispatcher   Speech Dispatcher
kernoops    Kernel Oops Tracking Daemon
pulse   PulseAudio daemon
rtkit   RealtimeKit
saned   
usbmux  usbmux daemon
colord  colord colour management daemon
hplip   HPLIP system user
lightdm Light Display Manager
kara    Kara
gdm Gnome Display Manager
Devices

Processor
Processors
AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor  2500.00MHz
AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor  1400.00MHz
AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor  1400.00MHz
AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor  1400.00MHz
AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor  1400.00MHz
AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor  3000.00MHz
Memory
Memory
Total Memory    4030356 kB
Free Memory 756348 kB
MemAvailable    2282652 kB
Buffers 190768 kB
Cached  1471888 kB
Cached Swap 312 kB
Active  2306812 kB
Inactive    610592 kB
Active(anon)    1221192 kB
Inactive(anon)  79900 kB
Active(file)    1085620 kB
Inactive(file)  530692 kB
Unevictable 256 kB
Mlocked 256 kB
Virtual Memory  4175868 kB
Free Virtual Memory 4174540 kB
Dirty   208 kB
Writeback   0 kB
AnonPages   1254756 kB
Mapped  398664 kB
Shmem   46344 kB
Slab    197212 kB
SReclaimable    157872 kB
SUnreclaim  39340 kB
KernelStack 8944 kB
PageTables  38084 kB
NFS_Unstable    0 kB
Bounce  0 kB
WritebackTmp    0 kB
CommitLimit 6191044 kB
Committed_AS    5108696 kB
VmallocTotal    34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed 293412 kB
VmallocChunk    34359440500 kB
HardwareCorrupted   0 kB
AnonHugePages   278528 kB
CmaTotal    0 kB
CmaFree 0 kB
HugePages_Total 0
HugePages_Free  0
HugePages_Rsvd  0
HugePages_Surp  0
Hugepagesize    2048 kB
DirectMap4k 313024 kB
DirectMap2M 3864576 kB
DirectMap1G 0 kB
PCI Devices
PCI Devices
Host bridge Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
PCI bridge  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
SATA controller Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
USB controller  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
USB controller  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
USB controller  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
USB controller  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
USB controller  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
USB controller  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
SMBus   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
IDE interface   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
Audio device    Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
ISA bridge  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
PCI bridge  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
USB controller  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
Host bridge Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
Host bridge Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
Host bridge Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
Host bridge Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
Host bridge Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
Host bridge Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
VGA compatible controller   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Audio device    Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
Ethernet controller Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
USB Devices
Printers
Printers
No printers found   
Battery
No batteries
No batteries found on this system   
Sensors
Input Devices
Input Devices
Power Button    
Power Button    
Logitech USB Receiver   
Logitech USB Receiver   
KMEPC USB Full Speed Gaming Mouse   
HDA ATI SB Front Mic    
HDA ATI SB Rear Mic 
HDA ATI SB Line 
HDA ATI SB Line Out 
HDA ATI SB Front Headphone  
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    3=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    7=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    8=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    9=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    10=
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    11=
Storage
SCSI Disks
ATA WDC WD1600AAJS-7    
ATA ST31000528AS    
DMI
BIOS
Date    01/15/2013
Vendor  American Megatrends Inc. (www.ami.com)
Version 080015
Board
Name    A960D+
Vendor  BIOSTAR Group (SEAGATE, www.seagate.com)
Resources
I/O Ports
0000-0cf7   PCI Bus 0000:00
0000-001f   dma1
0020-0021   pic1
0040-0043   timer0
0050-0053   timer1
0060-0060   keyboard
0061-0061   PNP0800:00
0064-0064   keyboard
0070-0071   rtc0
0080-008f   dma page reg
00a0-00a1   pic2
00c0-00df   dma2
00f0-00ff   PNP0C04:00
00f0-00ff   fpu
0170-0177   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
0170-0177   low-level driver for ATI IXP200/300/400
01f0-01f7   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
01f0-01f7   low-level driver for ATI IXP200/300/400
0376-0376   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
0376-0376   low-level driver for ATI IXP200/300/400
0378-037a   parport0
03c0-03df   vesafb
03f6-03f6   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
03f6-03f6   low-level driver for ATI IXP200/300/400
040b-040b   pnp 00:04
04d0-04d1   pnp 00:04
04d6-04d6   pnp 00:04
0800-0803   ACPI PM1a_EVT_BLK
0804-0805   ACPI PM1a_CNT_BLK
0808-080b   ACPI PM_TMR
0810-0815   ACPI CPU throttle
0820-0827   ACPI GPE0_BLK
0900-090f   pnp 00:04
0910-091f   pnp 00:04
0a30-0a3f   pnp 00:05
0b00-0b0f   pnp 00:04
0b20-0b3f   pnp 00:04
0c00-0c01   pnp 00:04
0c14-0c14   pnp 00:04
0c50-0c51   pnp 00:04
0c52-0c52   pnp 00:04
0c6c-0c6c   pnp 00:04
0c6f-0c6f   pnp 00:04
0cd0-0cd1   pnp 00:04
0cd2-0cd3   pnp 00:04
0cd4-0cd5   pnp 00:04
0cd6-0cd7   pnp 00:04
0cd8-0cdf   pnp 00:04
0cf8-0cff   PCI conf1
0d00-ffff   PCI Bus 0000:00
0e00-0e0f   pnp 00:05
0e80-0e8f   pnp 00:05
0f40-0f4f   pnp 00:05
8000-800f   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
8000-800f   AHCI SATA low-level driver
9000-9003   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
9000-9003   AHCI SATA low-level driver
a000-a007   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
a000-a007   AHCI SATA low-level driver
b000-b003   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
b000-b003   AHCI SATA low-level driver
c000-c007   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
c000-c007   AHCI SATA low-level driver
d000-dfff   PCI Bus 0000:01
d000-d0ff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
e000-efff   PCI Bus 0000:02
e800-e8ff   Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
e800-e8ff   RealTek RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver
fe00-fefe   pnp 00:04
ff00-ff0f   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
ff00-ff0f   low-level driver for ATI IXP200/300/400
Memory
00000000-00000fff   reserved
00001000-0009f3ff   System RAM
0009f400-0009ffff   reserved
000a0000-000bffff   PCI Bus 0000:00
000c0000-000cffff   Video ROM
000d0000-000dffff   PCI Bus 0000:00
000e6000-000fffff   reserved
000f0000-000fffff   System ROM
00100000-cffaffff   System RAM
01000000-017ce961   Kernel code
017ce962-01d3417f   Kernel data
01e9f000-01fe3fff   Kernel bss
cffb0000-cffbdfff   ACPI Tables
cffbe000-cffdffff   ACPI Non-volatile Storage
cffe0000-cfffffff   reserved
d0000000-dfffffff   PCI Bus 0000:00
d0000000-dfffffff   PCI Bus 0000:01
d0000000-dfffffff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
e0000000-efffffff   PCI MMCONFIG 0000 [bus 00-ff]
e0000000-efffffff   pnp 00:06
f0000000-febfffff   PCI Bus 0000:00
fdf00000-fdffffff   PCI Bus 0000:02
fdff8000-fdffbfff   Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
fdff8000-fdffbfff   RealTek RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver
fdfff000-fdffffff   Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
fdfff000-fdffffff   RealTek RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver
feaf4000-feaf7fff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
feaf4000-feaf7fff   ICH HD audio
feafa000-feafafff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
feafa000-feafafff   ohci_hcd
feafb000-feafbfff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
feafb000-feafbfff   ohci_hcd
feafc000-feafcfff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
feafc000-feafcfff   ohci_hcd
feafd000-feafdfff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
feafd000-feafdfff   ohci_hcd
feafe000-feafefff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
feafe000-feafefff   ohci_hcd
feaff400-feaff4ff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
feaff400-feaff4ff   ehci_hcd
feaff800-feaff8ff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
feaff800-feaff8ff   ehci_hcd
feaffc00-feafffff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
feaffc00-feafffff   AHCI SATA low-level driver
feb00000-febfffff   PCI Bus 0000:01
feb9c000-feb9ffff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
feb9c000-feb9ffff   ICH HD audio
feba0000-febbffff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
febc0000-febfffff   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
fec00000-fec003ff   IOAPIC 0
fec10000-fec1001f   pnp 00:04
fed00000-fed003ff   HPET 2
fed00000-fed003ff   PNP0103:00
fee00000-fee00fff   Local APIC
fee00000-fee00fff   pnp 00:03
ffb80000-ffbfffff   pnp 00:04
ffe00000-ffffffff   reserved
100000000-12effffff System RAM
12f000000-12fffffff RAM buffer
DMA
4   cascade
Network

Interfaces
Network Interfaces
eth0    963.72MiB   92.76MiB    192.168.0.4
lo  1.90MiB 1.90MiB 127.0.0.1
IP Connections
Connections
127.0.1.1:53        0.0.0.0:*   udp
127.0.0.1:631   LISTEN  0.0.0.0:*   tcp
0.0.0.0:51225       0.0.0.0:*   udp
192.168.0.4:51225   ESTABLISHED 68.227.36.25:54418  tcp
192.168.0.4:43838   ESTABLISHED 72.21.91.121:443    tcp
192.168.0.4:43837   ESTABLISHED 72.21.91.121:443    tcp
192.168.0.4:52819   ESTABLISHED 74.125.225.2:443    tcp
192.168.0.4:43840   ESTABLISHED 72.21.91.121:443    tcp
192.168.0.4:51225   ESTABLISHED 68.227.36.25:54418  tcp
192.168.0.4:52208   ESTABLISHED 157.56.53.42:12350  tcp
192.168.0.4:56360   ESTABLISHED 173.197.193.89:80   tcp
192.168.0.4:55254   ESTABLISHED 74.125.225.10:443   tcp
192.168.0.4:47729   ESTABLISHED 199.16.156.52:443   tcp
192.168.0.4:34992   ESTABLISHED 192.168.0.3:8009    tcp
192.168.0.4:43841   ESTABLISHED 72.21.91.121:443    tcp
192.168.0.4:38187   ESTABLISHED 198.252.206.25:443  tcp
192.168.0.4:52215   ESTABLISHED 192.168.0.3:8008    tcp
192.168.0.4:43839   ESTABLISHED 72.21.91.121:443    tcp
192.168.0.4:34346   ESTABLISHED 74.125.225.5:443    tcp
192.168.0.4:57744   ESTABLISHED 134.170.19.122:443  tcp
192.168.0.4:49034   ESTABLISHED 64.233.191.188:443  tcp
192.168.0.4:33707   ESTABLISHED 216.58.216.206:443  tcp
192.168.0.4:39725   ESTABLISHED 216.58.216.227:443  tcp
192.168.0.4:51225   ESTABLISHED 68.227.36.25:54418  tcp
192.168.0.4:50230   ESTABLISHED 65.55.223.15:40006  tcp
192.168.0.4:38170   ESTABLISHED 198.252.206.25:443  tcp
192.168.0.4:55114   ESTABLISHED 199.16.156.21:443   tcp
192.168.0.4:60975   ESTABLISHED 104.16.16.44:80 tcp
::1:631 ESTABLISHED ::1:58946   tcp6
::1:49724   CLOSE_WAIT  ::1:631 tcp6
::1:58946   ESTABLISHED ::1:631 tcp6
::1:58414   CLOSE_WAIT  ::1:631 tcp6
::1:49725   CLOSE_WAIT  ::1:631 tcp6
::1:631 ESTABLISHED ::1:58946   tcp6
127.0.0.1:36622     0.0.0.0:*   udp
0.0.0.0:65384       0.0.0.0:*   udp
0.0.0.0:51225       0.0.0.0:*   udp
127.0.1.1:53        0.0.0.0:*   udp
0.0.0.0:68      0.0.0.0:*   udp
0.0.0.0:37354       0.0.0.0:*   udp
0.0.0.0:631     0.0.0.0:*   udp
0.0.0.0:5353        0.0.0.0:*   udp
0.0.0.0:5353        0.0.0.0:*   udp
0.0.0.0:5353        0.0.0.0:*   udp
:::42831        :::*    udp6
:::25410        :::*    udp6
:::5353     :::*    udp6
:::5353     :::*    udp6
Routing Table
IP routing table
0.0.0.0 / 192.168.0.1   0.0.0.0 UG  eth0
169.254.0.0 / 0.0.0.0   255.255.0.0 U   eth0
192.168.0.0 / 0.0.0.0   255.255.255.0   U   eth0
ARP Table
ARP Table
192.168.0.3 80:d2:1d:2d:ed:e5   eth0
192.168.0.1 00:1d:d3:c0:d3:d1   eth0
DNS Servers
Name servers
127.0.1.1   
Statistics
IP
951779  Total packets received
699 With invalid addresses
0   Incoming packets discarded
0   Incoming packets discarded
951080  Incoming packets delivered
827022  Requests sent out
44  Outgoing packets dropped
288 Dropped because of missing route
ICMP
339 ICMP messages received
5   Input ICMP message failed.
1039    ICMP messages sent
0   ICMP messages failed
ICMPMSG
TCP
9224    Active connections openings
328 Passive connection openings
526 Failed connection attempts
412 Connection resets received
27  Connections established
525974  Segments received
391336  Segments send out
19057   Segments retransmited
80  Bad segments received.
1729    Resets sent
UDP
425223  Packets received
1105    Packets to unknown port received.
1   Packet receive errors
415667  Packets sent
UDPLITE
TCPEXT
8   Timeouts after SACK recovery
1549    TCP sockets finished time wait in fast timer
12  Congestion windows fully recovered without slow start
6824    Delayed acks sent
425347  Packet headers predicted
18431   Acknowledgments not containing data payload received
17111   Predicted acknowledgments
29  Times recovered from packet loss by selective acknowledgements
12  Congestion windows fully recovered without slow start
5   Congestion windows partially recovered using Hoe heuristic
20  Congestion windows recovered without slow start by DSACK
56  Congestion windows recovered without slow start after partial ack
8   Timeouts after SACK recovery
42  Fast retransmits
2   Forward retransmits
1   Retransmits in slow start
5314    Other TCP timeouts
1021    DSACKs sent for old packets
243 DSACKs received
418 Connections reset due to unexpected data
358 Connections reset due to early user close
485 Connections aborted due to timeout
IPEXT
Shared Directories
SAMBA
NFS
Benchmarks

CPU Blowfish
CPU Blowfish
This Machine    2500 MHz    2.313
Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor 1.50GHz (null)  26.1876862
PowerPC 740/750 (280.00MHz) (null)  172.816713
CPU CryptoHash
CPU CryptoHash
This Machine    2500 MHz    732.021
CPU Fibonacci
CPU Fibonacci
This Machine    2500 MHz    2.935
Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor 1.50GHz (null)  8.1375674
PowerPC 740/750 (280.00MHz) (null)  58.07682
CPU N-Queens
CPU N-Queens
This Machine    2500 MHz    0.588
FPU FFT
FPU FFT
This Machine    2500 MHz    1.528
FPU Raytracing
FPU Raytracing
This Machine    2500 MHz    18.787
Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor 1.50GHz (null)  40.8816714
PowerPC 740/750 (280.00MHz) (null)  161.312647
```

Generated with hardinfo.
Thanks in advance!

PS: While I thought it may be an issue with Gnome3 (don't ask me why...) I ran into the same problem while using Unity.

PPS: Audio from Audacity is also "staticky".

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't the software that is making it 'staticky', it will most likely be a hardware problem. Specifically, it could  be either the microphone itself, or microphone input port on your computer.

Also, sometimes having the microphone volume too high can cause some form of static and feedback.

Try using the microphone on another computer, and if the issue doesn't persist, you could try using a USB audio adapter for it, such as:

- [Sabrent USB External Stereo Sound Adapter for Windows and Mac](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IRVQ0F8)
- [Griffin Technology iMic USB Audio Device](http://Griffin%20Technology%20iMic%20USB%20Audio%20Device)

..or something similar.

Comment: I thought about that, but 2 days ago when I was on Windows, I had no (audio related) problems whatsoever. Still a valid point to bring up, thank you, and I'll look into the USB adapters.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the mic volume in Skype on Ubuntu (as mentioned above).

Comment: I have, and for a while I got lost because apparently I can use my HDMI TV's output as audio input? O_o was terrifying and weird. Switched it back shortly after, tried multiple volume levels, got to a point where they could barely hear me but still heard static.

edit: just asked if I was loud, at all. Apparently I'm not, but the buzzing bees are.